# Basic firebase database structure design decision

Tags: firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

**Situation:**

In the app we have up to 1000 schools. Every school has students and students are having lessons and are joining events (and more). We need to query quick and often lessons per student, per school per date. We have 2 designs in mind, wondering the best way to proceed.

1 - design with dedicated school node

2 - design with no dedicated school node

***Examples of two designs***

[image: Example of the 2 designs]

**PRO design 1**
- root ref to school user after login. noo need to query on school id's
- no need to mention school id's everywhere
- no need for node lessens per school and events per school
- rules on school level
...
**PRO design 2**
- more flatten data, as widely advised on the internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most NoSQL database structures, flattening and denormalising data is the best method. And that is exactly the case with Firebase too.

When you flatten your data, you get the following advantages :-

1. You're mostly only downloading the minimum required amount. That leads to efficiency and cost-effectiveness.
2. Your downloads are much faster - specially compared to the likes of SQL join queries.

Having said that, in your particular case, I think that it really depends on how much the `school` affects the logged in user.

Suppose that a `school` is only an attribute for a student, and serves no other purpose, then the second database is the way to go. For example, if the books a student can get are independent of the school she goes to, then the second database style is more suited.

However, if a `school` categories students into groups that define their interaction with the database, then the first database structure is the way to go. An example of this is that a student can only get a book when its available in the school she goes to.

Regardless of your decision, I would like to commend you on the fact that you have flattened your database quite well in both your structures! And my personal suggestion would be to go with the one that is more convenient to code, read and maintain for you.

Comment: All interaction a student does with the database is related to one school only, and schools never share the same objectives. One school might be in China, the other in Mexico.  So, I think to go for option one. Thanks a lot for your feedback! It did help me to make a decision.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad that I could help. If you think that my answer would help others stuck in a similar situation, then do accept it. It'll make it easier for others to find and perhaps, trust.